# Does GPS need internet to find out latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does GPS require Internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128990/does-gps-require-internet)

I need to calculate the latitude and longitude only using GPS.
Do GPS need internet for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, GPS Doesn't required any Internet for getting your location. It is just a satellite position system. For a brief description you can refer this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131727/1649309)

Comment: But you will need the internet for doing anything useful with the coordinates you receive.. Mostly.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy I agree with you but that is nothing related to question.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I only added it as a comment... :-)

Comment: @VinaySShenoy - I would disagree. To run my Sygic, I dont need internet at all as everything is stored locally on the phone. And it works much better than Google navigation when travelling to remote areas :-)

PS: Not trying to promote Sygic, just making a point about internet :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have heard of A-GPS, or assisted GPS, an Internet connection will help to "assist" the GPS, or to get a quick "fix". But it is not required at all.

Personal experience - without any network or Internet, my phone sometimes takes as long as 10 minutes to get a "fix". If I turn on A-GPS, it gets a lock within a minute.

> Assisted GPS, generally abbreviated as A-GPS or aGPS, is a system that can under certain conditions improve the startup performance, or time-to-first-fix (TTFF), of a GPS satellite-based positioning system

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS

Answer (score 1):

A device GPS does need internet ( initially) to get a list from which device can check the positioning of the satellites.

Once the list is fetched i.e on map you can see clearly your location with accuracy of <40m
you can turn off the data and gps will keep a track of your location. 
( unless you close the application)

Basically GPS is nothing but a timestamps message received from a satellites on comparison of 3 such messages( x,y and z coordinates) and the satellite relative positioning the device derives its location. The more the satellites the better the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of internet to findout the Lattitude and Longtitude...You just have GPS ON in your device...

Answer (score 0):

GPS is exactly the technology that calculates latitudes and longitudes from the the *data* it receives from at least 4 visible satellites.

However many consumer receivers, especially mobile phones that have GPS receivers, are really insensitive and require internet connection to get an estimate of the data, time and trajectories of the satellites (called ephemeris).

Answer (score 0):

No, GPS doesnt need internet. i think you are mixing about showing location in map.
Simply to find GPS location you dont need internet. but if you want to show ur location on Map than it requires Internet. to map ur current location on MAP. as Mapview required internet