# getting latitude and longitude of an address in android using gps and without using internet connection

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I want to know if gps can be used to get the latitude and longitude of an address.I've just began to work on gps on android.My problem is that if the user does not have internet connection, i want him to be able to get the latitude and longitude of an address.Can gps do that or it is only used to get current location.If not are they any other way of getting this done.I;m using google maps and i've also tried to get geocoding as mentioned in some posts,but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the point of what GPS is designed to do.

Your phone's GPS doesn't do anything with an address.  All GPS does is get the latitude/longitude of your current position, nothing more.  The phone (via an internet connection) is able to identify your address based on the Latitude/Longitude that the GPS provides by using 3rd party provides (such as Google Maps)

It sounds like you just want to get the latitude/longitude of any address, not just for the device's physical location.  That does not require GPS at all.  But it needs an internet connection in order to access a provider to perform the geocoding.

A answer I provided to [Does GPS require Internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128990/does-gps-require-internet/12131727#12131727) is a somewhat related to your issue.  The 2nd to last paragraphs are pertinent here as well

> While it requires a significant amount of effort, you can write your own tool to do the reverse geocoding, but you still need to be able to house the data somewhere as the amount of data required to do this is far more you can store on a phone, which means you still need an internet connection to do it. If you think of tools like Garmin GPS Navigation units, they do store the data locally, so it is possible, but you will need to optimize it for maximum storage and would probably need more than is generally available in a phone.

So effectively, you theoretically could write your own tool, cache data locally and query it as needed, but that not something that is easily done.

Answer (score 3):

From your question,

If you are using Google Map and GeoCoder class that means you must have Internet connection. And moreover when you are working with GPS, again you must have Internet Connection. If you are using GPS_PROVIDER then you required open sky type environment and for NETWORK_PROVIDER you can fetch gps details inside a room,but for both provider Internet is must.

Comment: in some cases i have internet connection.but what i wanted to know is that if i do not have internet connection is there a way to get the the coordinates of an address i.e i wanted gps to do that.

Comment: @user2327579 if you not have internet connection for 4-5 minutes that time you can use NETWORK_PROVIDER or you can use getLastKnownPosition() method.

Comment: that's ok but i want to know if gps can be used to get coordinates of an address, not my current location.I think that it is not possible.Is it so?

Comment: Not gps but Geocoder is there which can accept lat-lng and output the address or viceversa.