# Can I rely on GPS location without an internet connection for a mobile app?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I want to develop an app capable of drawing a path based on the user's location over time. The issue is that it sounds like GPS, without A-GPS, is pretty slow. I can't always rely on the user having an internet connection. I really don't want to abandon the idea of this project because of this issue.

When GPS location is pinged, after I receive the location after x seconds or minutes, will it be the user's location at the time I requested it or their current location? If it's their location at the time of the request, I don't think I'll have an issue as I can just save all of the data points afterwards.

Comment: Gps fix is always the current location + inaccuracy. You can register for both network and gps providers for location. But keep in mind GPS works outdoors mostly.

Comment: Of course you can rely on gps only. I even always switch off a-gps. Look at a car navigator: it uses gps only. What else? Only gps is accurate. And no internet needed. Of course not. Gps does not work in tunnels and buildings as you will know.

Answer (score 0):

In short, Yes. You don't need internet to access the hardware based gps sensor. It's been answered in another post.

[Does GPS require Internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128990/does-gps-require-internet)

As far as the coordinates being the devices current location or the time requested; Im not entirely sure but I think when you receive the location, it's the current location. You really don't have control when a location update occurs. What you probably want to do is request updates often to ensure you are working with your current location.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware that you don't need an internet connection for GPS. My issue is, is relying purely on GPS, and not A-GPS, good enough to constantly get and store someone's location.

Comment: @MichaelBlake Shouldn't the real GPS signal be much better?

Comment: is that Fused location API needs internet