# Is there any way to get geolocation from mobile without any network

Tags: java, android

newbie there.

I'm wondering, is there possibly a way to create an (Android/iOS, whatever) app that would locate the user as precise as possible but without any network? For example underground, where you can't even call or send a text.

Is there any way that we can get the geolocation without these? It might sound like a dumb question, I just want to be sure that it's 100% not feasible for now.
If you think there is way, even expensive or whatever it needs, please let me know.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Hum, hello btw!

Comment: Fundamentally, the phone would need to communicate with something - be it a Wifi hotspot, mobile tower, or satellite, to be able to be told its location.  I guess in theory one can look at accelerometers, but those assume that the phone was connected to something since it was switched on, and even then is likely to be very imprecise.

Comment: Virtually all smart phones have GPS antenna. This system is independent of internet. The issue is, depending on application, whether or not you have a map to view the coordinates on. You can either have one pre loaded, or use an app just to tell you your raw coordinates. Again, depends on application. Edit: As per you question, without even looking myself, I promise you there are 100s of apps to simply view your coordinates without internet.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can use GPS, bacause GPS can use only saltellite, so, you don't need internet.

your can refer to this post:
[Does GPS require Internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128990/does-gps-require-internet)

Comment: GPS doesn't need the Internet, but I suggest you use GoogleApiClient's FusedLocationProvider, which based on different conditions automatically uses the best location tracking service.  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient