# Strange behaviour while looking for locations in android 7 and 8

Tags: android, locationmanager

I'm doing a app to collect pure GPS locations. 
So I choice use locationmanager whit ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

I don't want use google play services to locations because, I believe, it joins locations from various providers without user control.

I want a specific app to test the device GPS chipset, so I want only GPS locations no matters what time it become ready.

I do a app as described and it works fine in my cellphone Xiaomi Redmi S2 whit android 8.

But in a cellphone Quantum MUV with android 7 it don't get any locations.

Somebody knows some specific issue about location manager running in android 7 or in Quantum MUV cellphone?

Comment: From what I could [find](https://www.phonemore.com/quantum-muv-pro-16gb/specs/2732) the Quantum MUV may only have [A-GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131727/295004) which would require a data connection to Google or mobile provider. If you've waited >15 minutes in an open sky area without getting location, that may be the case.

Comment: But A-GPS encompass GPS, am I right?

Comment: I would say yes, but the Wikipedia article on [A-GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS) covers the no-network situation. Unfortunately marketing material may not know the difference between true GPS chip and A-GPS feature.